# Spring boot Manually Inject @Configuration bean registration before Initialization

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to know if I can manually inject @Configuration classes (that will fire inject bean creations) manually.

Desired working code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EnvironmentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ap = SpringApplication.run(EnvironmentApplication.class, args);
        ap.getBean(Car.class); //I hope this will be created
    }

}
```

The Car bean would be injected by ManualConfiguration.class. But keep in mind that ManualConfiguration is not scanned (imagine in other top level packaging hierarchy)

```
@Configuration
public class ManualConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Car car() {
        return new Car();
    }
}
```

My question : I am trying to add the @Configuration class (ManuallyConfiguration.class) manually via BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.

```
@Component
public class Processors implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor{

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("postProcessBeanFactory   ->  "+beanFactory);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry   ->  "+registry);
        GenericBeanDefinition bd = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        bd.setBeanClass(ManualConfiguration.class);
        registry.registerBeanDefinition("manualCarLoading", bd);
    }
}
```

But the ManuallyConfiguration.class is not interpreted as @Configuration class and related beans are not created.

Update: To clarify , I want to do manually like @import(MyConfiguration.class)  annotation works
(Sure in a previous phase before BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor I think, maybe after first spring boot scan phase)

Sure, is a "why do you want to do this?" absurd question, but I want to know how to do work in this way

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try without implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor

My excample

```
    @Configuration
    public class ConfigurationProvider {
    
        
        @Bean
        public ConfigurationItem cessionBuyersImportConfigurationItem() {
            return new ImportConfigurationItem(1);
        }
        @Bean
        public ConfigurationItem cessionBuyersImportConfigurationItem() {
            return new ImportConfigurationItem(2);
        }
    
    }
    
    
    @Component
public class Configuration {

 public Configuration(List<ConfigurationItem> configurationItems) {
       // do something with beans
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel , thanks for answer!. But in this case the correct hierarchy is needed to sucessfully scan will found the '@configuration' and then defined beans will be loaded. But my question is about manual '@Configuration' class loading  (like @import annotation works , but doing programatically). I am going to clarify the question